# Is it safe to run precompiled protobuf binaries on older environment ( Ubuntu 16.04 )?

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers

I want to update the protobuf version my application uses. I see that protobuf have already precompiled binaries (https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/releases/tag/v3.11.2) available but I don't really understand if that is safe to use them on my Ubuntu 16.04 environment as I think they might be compiled with newer gcc.

The version I'm using at the moment is 2.6.1 which comes from the official ubuntu repository. There is no available protobuf > 3.4.x in the repo.

From my understanding, there is protoc compiler that compiles *.proto file into the language-dependent definition and libraries used for linkage like (libprotobuf-dev). Is that possible that precompiled libraries or protoc binary are linking to a newer version of libc/smthg and that is not safe to use on my system?

Do I have to compile protobuf from sources?

Comment: Define "safe". It's Ubuntu, you have no official guarantee whatsoever anyway. Software is provided "as is". Even if you recompile the universe, "safety" has yet to be defined.

Comment: By 'safe' I understand - the library would work as on compilation environment and no issue would be introduced by the environment difference.

Comment: no such guarantees even with the same version compiled, let alone different binaries.